# ReactNative with TensorFlow Object detection

Tags: react-native, tensorflow

I am a beginner in TensorFlow, and I am currently working on developing a React Native app for auto-correcting bubble sheet (answer sheet).

The main objective of the app is to utilize the camera to detect the answer paper in real-time and highlight four black boxes in the corners to ensure that the paper is positioned correctly.

I would greatly appreciate any suggestions on the plugins or libraries that would be useful for this project. Additionally, if there are any code references available, I would be grateful for any recommendations or resources that I can look into for guidance.